# Why does my custom UITableViewCell return the wrong width when calling self.frame.width?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This has been answered in a comment by @Kevin. I wasn't calling `layoutSubviews`.

Everything is created programmatically. Nothing is done via storyboards. Here is a stripped down version of the tableView code:

```
func configure(cell: UITableViewCell, for indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? HistoryTableViewCell else {
        return
    }
// I set up the cells various properties here.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: historyCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HistoryTableViewCell
    configure(cell: cell, for: indexPath)

    return cell
}
```

Here is a stripped down version of my UITableViewCell:

```
class HistoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:)")
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let  test = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: 10))
            test.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            self.addSubview(test)    
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    }
}
```

Notice I set the test views width to self.frame.width. Which produces this:
[image: iphone 7+ screenshot]

Printing self.frame.width in the HistoryTableViewCell results in 320 which is the width of an iPhone 5s. Any idea why? I'm assuming it's something like I am creating the cell before something so it defaults to the smallest size.

Another odd thing is if I try and set the test views center.x to self.center.x it stays where it is which I think is weird as the background colour shows the cell is the width of the screen.

Thanks

Comment: If you use self.contentView.frame.width instead of self.frame.width , then what is the result?

Comment: The width probably isn't set at that point, try resizing in `layoutSubviews` (remember to call `super`).

Comment: That said, if you have to ask this, you really should be using autolayout unless you have a really good reason not to.

Comment: @3stud1ant3 same result.

Comment: Thanks very much @Kevin layoutSubviews fixed the issue. I will admit I am fairly new to laying out views programmatically (especially with tableViews) but you have to start learning some time.

Comment: Even if you are going to use programmatic layout, I suggest you add constraints programatically and use auto layout.  Setting frames directly is a lot harder when it comes to adapting to new devices and handling rotation etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you don't want to use autolayout or autoresizingmaske, have UI components as property and update their frame in the layoutSubview.

```
class HistoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

let test = UIView()

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:)")
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    self.test.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.contentView.addSubview(test)    
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    test.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: 10)
}
```